# iOS app with content downloading automatically (about App Store policy)

Tags: ios, download, app-store, policy, restrictions

I have an app in the App Store with a number of different soundboards. I release updates every once in a while with new content. Some content however is forbidden by Apple (foul language) resulting in updates being rejected. To make updating faster and easier, I'm building an update which automatically downloads new content from a server. So my question is; what will happen when content in an update is found inappropriate by Apple? Will my app be removed from the App Store? Will they ban my developer account? Will they even find out? The app is in Dutch and therefore it's quite hard te determine what is permissible by App Store policy and what is not. I had some explicit content accepted in updates, while other seemingly less explicit content got rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is never reviewed by the same person and so much depends on the reviewer. There is a Dutch review team so regarding not noticing due to language, I wouldn't rely on it. 
Now I have released apps that breach API terms with youtube and the apps existed on the appstore for a long time. Once it was brought to Apple's attention, they removed the app but did not suspend my developer account (I imagine that you have to break policy repeatedly for this and do something much worse than simply having foul language in your app). In my opinion, If Apple notices that your app has foul language on it, they will simply remove it from sale and ask you to submit an update which addresses the issue as they did in my case.

Comment: I think I will just go for it then and judge new content the best I can based on past updates. Thanks for sharing your experience with me, very good explanation of all the factors!